C/C++ IntelliSense extention fails to start. Also fails to perform the normal operations (e.g. auto completions, etc.)
For some strange reason, the vscode C/C++ extion[s] stopped working today. Yesterday evening everything was just fine, and I didn't do any modifications between.
Environment:
PC: HP ProBook 430 G4, 8Gib RAM, 4 Intel® Core™ i5-7200U,
OS: Ubuntu 24.04 LTS 64bit.

Versions:
kernel: Linux 6.8.0-36-generic (latest as of today).

vscode: 1.90.2 (snap):
    Commit: 5437499feb04f7a586f677b155b039bc2b3669eb,
    Date: 2024-06-18T22:33:48.698Z,
    Electron: 29.4.0,
    ElectronBuildId: 9728852,
    Chromium: 122.0.6261.156,
    Node.js: 20.9.0 V8: 12.2.281.27-electron.0.

plugins:
    C/C++ IntelliSense:   v1.20.5 (release),
    C/C++ Extension Pack: v1.3.0C/C++,
    Themes:               v2.0.0.

Error message 1:
Unable to start the C/C++ language server. IntelliSense features will be disabled. Error: TypeError: entries.forEach is not a function

Source: C/C++

Error message 2:
Sending document notification textDocument/didOpen failed.
    
Source: C/C++

Expecting:

plugin should start normally and perform it's operation normally.

Non of the below helped till now:

Full system packages update (sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade).
Full snap packages update (snap-store).
PC reboot.
Disable/Restart/Enable of all plugins.
Uninstalling/Installing of all plugins.
Uninstall/Install of vscode snap (including removal of all .vscode directories systemwide).

Log for error 1:
2024-06-30 22:43:21.924 [error] [ExtensionListenerError] Extension 'ms-vscode.cpptools' FAILED to handle event: AssertionError
[ERR_ASSERTION]: Unsupported client: Error: [ExtensionListenerError] Extension 'ms-vscode.cpptools' FAILED to handle event: AssertionError
[ERR_ASSERTION]: Unsupported client
    at n.value (/snap/code/162/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:163:20749)
    at l.y (/snap/code/162/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:82:664)
    at l.fire (/snap/code/162/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:82:881)
    at p.$acceptEditorPropertiesChanged (/snap/code/162/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:155:33458)
    at E.S (/snap/code/162/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:150:5970)
    at E.Q (/snap/code/162/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:150:5736)
    at E.M (/snap/code/162/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:150:4762)
    at E.L (/snap/code/162/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:150:3589)
    at n.value (/snap/code/162/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:150:2282)
    at l.y (/snap/code/162/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:82:664)
    at l.fire (/snap/code/162/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:82:881)
    at s.fire (/snap/code/162/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:107:14502)
    at n.value (/snap/code/162/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:176:8481)
    at l.y (/snap/code/162/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:82:664)
    at l.fire (/snap/code/162/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:82:881)
    at s.fire (/snap/code/162/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:107:14502)
    at MessagePortMain.<anonymous> (/snap/code/162/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:176:6631)
    at MessagePortMain.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at MessagePortMain._internalPort.emit (node:electron/js2c/utility_init:2:2285)

Log for error 2:
[Error - 1:22:19 PM] Sending document notification
textDocument/didOpen failed.
AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Unsupported client
    at DefaultClient.enqueue (/home/$USER/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.cpptools-1.21.0-linux-x64/dist/src/main.js:76006:25)
    at didOpen (/home/$USER/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.cpptools-1.21.0-linux-x64/dist/src/main.js:82488:84)
    at DidOpenTextDocumentFeature.callback (/home/$USER/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.cpptools-1.21.0-linux-x64/dist/src/main.js:99367:33)
    at /home/$USER/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.cpptools-1.21.0-linux-x64/dist/src/main.js:99352:22
    at n.value (/snap/code/162/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:163:20722)
    at l.y (/snap/code/162/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:82:664)
    at l.z (/snap/code/162/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:82:734)
    at l.fire (/snap/code/162/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:82:950)
    at n.value (/snap/code/162/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:153:80173)
    at l.y (/snap/code/162/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:82:664)
    at l.fire (/snap/code/162/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:82:881)
    at m.acceptDocumentsAndEditorsDelta (/snap/code/162/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:155:30660)
    at m.$acceptDocumentsAndEditorsDelta (/snap/code/162/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:155:29168)
    at E.S (/snap/code/162/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:150:5970)
    at E.Q (/snap/code/162/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:150:5736)
    at E.M (/snap/code/162/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:150:4762)
    at E.L (/snap/code/162/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:150:3589)
    at n.value (/snap/code/162/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:150:2282)
    at l.y (/snap/code/162/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:82:664)
    at l.fire (/snap/code/162/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:82:881)
    at s.fire (/snap/code/162/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:107:14502)
    at n.value (/snap/code/162/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:176:8481)
    at l.y (/snap/code/162/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:82:664)
    at l.fire (/snap/code/162/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:82:881)
    at s.fire (/snap/code/162/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:107:14502)
    at MessagePortMain.\<anonymous\> (/snap/code/162/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:176:6631)
    at MessagePortMain.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at MessagePortMain.\_internalPort.emit (node:electron/js2c/utility_init:2:2285)


Can you check if you have a folder named ms-vscode.cpptools in .vscode/extensions/ location? If this folder does exist, try deleting it as it may be containing bad or corrupt cache.

Nope, sorry. In fact, this was included in the 6th item of "what I tried..." above.

Managed to capture the log for error #1 - added to original body text.
BTW, what is the correct way of reading the call stack n the log? top to bottom or bottom to top?
@Dimitar

@Shumlik Hen bottom to top almost always. Call stack will give you usually the exception type at the top then go from the deepest level to the highest level of call.

Great, this means I wasn't barking at the wrong tree when trying to figure which JS was actually failing.
@Dimitar

Found the cause - there was a syntax error in one of my project's JSON files under $HOME/$PROJECT/.vscode/.
Can't understand why this error was not captured or highlighed in any way when they were openend in the editor. Maybe there is a JSON plugin that needs to be installed for that.
